# 極座標における点の移動を計算したい

Tags: 数学

以下の様な問題を考えます。

xy平面上でまず、原点Oからx軸に沿って、長さr_1移動します（この時、角度θ_1=0）。
次に、角度θ_2で長さr_2移動し、さらに角度θ_3で長さr_3移動し、
その後も同様に続けていきます。
以下の図の青い線で、上記の移動を示しています。

[image: 座標遷移の図]
ここで例えば、
図の赤い点線の長さであるs_3やs_4、
赤い点線とx軸との角度であるφ_3やφ_4は、
rとθを用いてどのように計算できるでしょうか？

また、s_nやφ_nは、rとθを用いてどのような一般式で計算できるでしょうか？

最終的には、三次元極座標系において一般化したいと思っています。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: theta_i は前の線分と次の線分のなす角ですか．それとも次の線分とx軸とのなす角ですか

Comment: 対象の経路を、単位ベクトルと長さで表現してはどうでしょう。
そうすると、座標系に依存する部分が、単位ベクトルの内部表現に隠ぺいできるため、
最終的な合計移動角度の計算の基本構造が座標系に関わらず相似になります。

Comment: @takoika theta_i は、前の線分と次の線分のなす角です。

Comment: @Uncle-Kei すみません、私の理解不足なのですが、「経路を単位ベクトルと長さで表現」というところが、ちょっとイメージがつきません。具体的に例えば、r_2やr_3はどのような表現になるのでしょうか？

Comment: 単位ベクトルは長さ1で、方向のみを指し示します。
XY平面なら、座標原点から始まり半径1の円周上で終わるベクトルとなります。
すなわちX軸に対する角度がθである単位ベクトル Aの要素xu,yuはそれぞれxu=cos(θ),yu=sin(θ)と表せます。
これに長さの属性rがあるベクトルの場合にはX軸の要素は(r)×(xu)と表現できます。
開始点属性p0が加わると任意の移動を表現できますが、本件では不要かもしれません。
また、XY平面の場合ベクトルの加算は対象ベクトルのそれぞれの要素の加算で表せます。
で、最初の移動は、長さr1、方向単位ベクタv1( cos(0), sin( 0))で表せ、
次の移動は長さr2、方向単位ベクタv2( cos(180-θ2), sin(180-θ2))
なので、総合的な移動は、x方向が cos(0)+cos(180-θ2)となります。
yも同様に計算できます。
これらに逆三角関数を施すなどすれば総合的移動角度が算定できます。

Comment: @Uncle-Kei ありがとうございます。直前のベクトルの向きを正としてθを計算し、そのcosやsinをどんどん足しこんでいけば良いのですね。

Answer (score 2):

iステップ後の位置を`p_i`としてベクトル表示をすると`p_i=(sum(r_i*cos(D_i),sum(r_i*sin(D_i)))`とかけます． ここで`D_i`はiステップめの進行方向のx軸からみた角度でとします．  `D_i`は`sum(pi-theta_i)` とかけます． この`p_i`を使えばベクトルの長さ `s_i` は `s_i=sqrt(p_i_x**2+p_i_y**2)`とかけます． 角度は`phi_i=arctan(p_i_y/p_i_x)`です．

Comment: 手計算して確認して、今コードを書いています。三次元極座標でもうまくいきそうです。ありがとうございます。